# Discrete Mathematics-Relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I test the properties of the following relation:

**R={((a,b),(c,d)): ad=bd } where a,b,c and d real numbers.**

We used to test the properties for only two variables!!

Please anyone have any idea???

Thank you.

Comment: Could you specify which "properties" you mean? Are you sure that it is $ad=bd$ and not $ad=bc$?

Comment: Reflexive, symmetric and transitive. This is a question our prof. gave us.

Comment: if it is $ad=bc$, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785554/equivalence-relation-and-classes-confusion/785565#785565

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is a relation on pairs. Where you are accustomed to check e.g. $x \mathrel{R} y$, you'll have to check pairs, like $(u, v) \mathrel{R} (x, y)$

Answer (score 1):

This relation can be expressed:

> Two pairs of real numbers $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are related iff the two components of $\vec u$ are the same or the second component of $\vec v$ is 0.

If with 'properties' you mean reflexivity, symmetry and transivity, we have:

- It isn't reflexive, since $(2,1)$ isn't related to itself.
- It isn't symmetric, since $(2,1)R(2,0)$ but $(2,0)$ is not related to $(2,1)$
- It isn't transitive: $(2,1)R(0,0)R(1,2)$ but $(2,1)$ isn't related to $(1,2)$.

Comment: This is the first time I ask for help from a website, and  within half an hour I found response.you guys are awesome !! Thank you